# (change) Working only after pressing enter in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, web-deployment, angular2-forms

I want to show a list which shows the rows matching the user entered value in the text box.
List must keep changing dynamically as user keeps inputting values.
that's why I tried using (change) event listener on the input text box.
but list changes only after I press 'Enter' button.
Here's the code.

```
<tr>
        <td><input type = "text" [(ngModel)] = "writerSuggest" (change) = "getWriterList($event)" /></td>
</tr>
<tr *ngFor="let writers of writerListShow">
        <td style="cursor: pointer;" (click) = "onWriterClick(writers.name)">{{writers.name}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td *ngIf = 'writerErr' >No writers with given name</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You can use `(keypress)`,`(keydown)` and `(keyup)` events.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ngmodelChange event.

```
<td><input type = "text" [ngModel] = "writerSuggest" (ngModelChange) = "getWriterList($event)" /></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ng modelChange which detects change of bound variables's value.
like

```
<input type = "text" [(ngModel)] = "writerSuggest" (ngModelChange) = "getWriterList($event)" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `ngModelChange`

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iqdbs8?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)